# Python: How do I count unique list elements and put that count as dictionary values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm doing a project for a class. I'm at a stage where I need to count disaster areas. I've defined a function that is supposed to pull the names from the multi-dimensional list, count the # of times each unique element occurs, and then marry those two items as keys & values respectively in a new dictionary. I have managed to do the first part(establish the areas as keys), but I can't figure out how to get the unique counts for how often each area occurs in the list, and assign them as the values.

I've attempted to use a variable to count each one, but the results are all wrong. The counts coming out seem to be random.

```
# areas affected by each hurricane
areas_affected = [['Central America', 'Mexico', 'Cuba', 'Florida', 'The Bahamas'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'The Bahamas', 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada'], ['The Bahamas', 'Northeastern United States'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'Jamaica', 'Cayman Islands', 'Cuba', 'The Bahamas', 'Bermuda'], ['The Bahamas', 'Cuba', 'Florida', 'Texas', 'Tamaulipas'], ['Jamaica', 'Yucatn Peninsula'], ['The Bahamas', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'The Carolinas', 'Virginia'], ['Southeastern United States', 'Northeastern United States', 'Southwestern Quebec'], ['Bermuda', 'New England', 'Atlantic Canada'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'Central America'], ['Texas', 'Louisiana', 'Midwestern United States'], ['Central America'], ['The Caribbean', 'Mexico', 'Texas'], ['Cuba', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['The Caribbean', 'Central America', 'Mexico', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['Mexico'], ['The Caribbean', 'United States East coast'], ['The Caribbean', 'Yucatn Peninsula', 'Mexico', 'South Texas'], ['Jamaica', 'Venezuela', 'Central America', 'Hispaniola', 'Mexico'], ['The Caribbean', 'United States East Coast'], ['The Bahamas', 'Florida', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['Central America', 'Yucatn Peninsula', 'South Florida'], ['Greater Antilles', 'Bahamas', 'Eastern United States', 'Ontario'], ['The Caribbean', 'Venezuela', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['Windward Islands', 'Jamaica', 'Mexico', 'Texas'], ['Bahamas', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['Cuba', 'United States Gulf Coast'], ['Greater Antilles', 'Central America', 'Florida'], ['The Caribbean', 'Central America'], ['Nicaragua', 'Honduras'], ['Antilles', 'Venezuela', 'Colombia', 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada'], ['Cape Verde', 'The Caribbean', 'British Virgin Islands', 'U.S. Virgin Islands', 'Cuba', 'Florida'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'Virgin Islands', 'Puerto Rico', 'Dominican Republic', 'Turks and Caicos Islands'], ['Central America', 'United States Gulf Coast (especially Florida Panhandle)']]

def area_counter(areas_affected):
    areas = {}
    count = 0
    splits = [item[-1].split(",") for item in areas_affected]
    flat = [item for l in splits for item in l]
    for i in range(len(flat)):
        count += 1
        areas[flat[i]] = {"Count": [count]}
    return areas
print(area_counter(areas_affected))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a defaultdict with a lambda that returns 0 for uninitialized items

```
from collections import defaultdict
areas = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
```

and whenever you use that area as a key just simply update it by one

```
areas[key] += 1
```

Let me know if this helps or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultdict` from the `collections` package.

If you prefer to do it manually, you can do it first by extracting all the keys and then counting the occurrences for each key.

```
keys = set()
for item in areas_affected:
    keys.update(item)

dic = {}
for k in keys:
    counter = 0
    for item in areas_affected:
        if k in item:
            counter += 1
        
    dic[k] = counter
```